# Simple compareTo in string

Tags: java, string, compareto

The simple code give me output :-12 for line 1 and 0 for Line 2

How does compareTo compare these strings?

```
String str1=new String("hello:");
String str2=new String("this is sitansu");
String str3=new String("HELLO:");
System.out.println(str1.compareTo(str2));//LIne 1
System.out.println(str1.compareTo(str3));//Line 2
```

Comment: Not true: http://ideone.com/q9pfiQ it gives -12 and 32

Comment: You've found the documentation... not bad :-) not many come so far. What exacly don't you understand? The last paragraph gives the exact answer to your question...

Comment: The best answer you can get is looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: It does it as documented, and the documentation is freely available online. If you want complete details, look at the source code which comes with the JDK and is thus also freely available.

Comment: thanks @MarounMaroun  Actually i want this

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the strings lexicographically when you use compareTo(). This returns numbers that compare the strings based on the fact that each character in a string is actually an ASCII value (a number) to the computer. This method returns 0 if the strings are the same.

You could use `System.out.println(str1.equals(str2))`to compare the strings for equality. This will return True if they are the same.